# How can I successfully sign an APK?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to sign a modified (by me) APK using Java JDK's keytool (this is my very first time) and I'm encountering multiple errors. All I've really been wanting to do is add assets/textures to the APK (basically changing its size) so I can have more slots for bodies/legs/arms etc. I've been researching for months and it's really frustrating because I see others doing it.

Anyway the main error I can't get past is `keytool error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: keystore.jks (Access is denied)` and I don't know exactly what that means. Can someone help? I'm using a x86 based program by the way.

Comment: It means that you (your user) doesn't have the access to the .jks file (the key file). It means that you don't have the permission (it is closed to reading or writing). Check it's permissions and try changing it.

Comment: How do I check its permissions?

Comment: You are on linux system?

Comment: No, Windows 10 (32-bit).

Comment: Look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

`Access is denied` - It means that you (your user) doesn't have the access to the wanted `.jks` file (the key file). It means that you don't have the permission (it is closed to reading or writing). Check it's permissions and try changing it.

You can find information on how to change windows10 file permissions [here](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/).